# Pandas df how to show where df['col']+df['col2'] don't match

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a single `df` with two columns `df['A']` and `df['B']` (`df['C'])` is timestamp). `A`'s data is a username, and in `B` is a number.

I want to extract where the username+number values are A) the same, and B) different, i.e. so to show where username has >1 (different) numbers.

Is that possible?

I tested with `set(df.A+df.B)` to get unique values, but I can't do anything with this.

EDIT:

I need to make this more clear....

I'm picturing a loop whereby I start at index `0`, grab its value in `df['A']` and `df['B']`, then I iterate through index n+1...nth row looking for a match on index `0`'s `df['B']`, if match exists then check if the matches `df['A']` != `df['A']` of index `0` and if it does not then print both index's data, then move to index n+1 and repeat the process. Does that make sense?

So this will basically only print data from a dataframe `df` where the username string (in `df['A']`) is associated with different numbers (`df['B']` values).

Comment: `df.loc[df['A'] == df['B']]` and `df.loc[df['A'] != df['B']]` ? But it's not clear this is exactly what you want as you refer to getting 'unique values'. If not, could you post sample data and expected outcome?

Comment: To better illustrate what you want, you should include a sample data and expected output.

Comment: There are a variety of things to do with `pandas.DataFrame.duplicated`, `pandas.DataFrame.groupby`, and/or `nunique` but I can't tell what you have nor what you want.  Consider providing a [mcve]

Comment: Are `('foo', '11')` and `('foo1', '1')` valid `(username, number)` pairs? If so, adding them would produce the same value, `'foo11'`, but presumably the pairs should be considered distinct. Thus, adding is usually not the right (most robust, bug-free) way to determine uniqueness.

Comment: @Brendan - does my update make any sense?

Answer (score 1):

You can look for duplicated combinations of two columns with:

```py
df[df[['A', 'B']].duplicated()]
```